# NITF raster (Worldview) failing to load correctly in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, coordinates, pansharpening, nitf

I am attempting to load in multispectral and panchromatic rasters in NITF format into QGIS in order to run a pan sharpening process using OTB toolbox.

Loading in the panchromatic is fine, but upon loading the multispectral it does not position correctly over the panchromatic, zooming in seems to just make it jump around to different locations?

[image]

It does the same in QGIS 3.10 and also 2.18

I tested loading the same files into another GIS app **Global Mapper** and they load fine but it does check the following before loading:

[image]

Fully zoomed out multispectral raster in Global Mapper looks like this:
[image]

Is QGIS not handling the georeference meta data (RPC or corner coordinates) correctly?

**Panchromatic gdalinfo**:

```
F:\GIS\CD5514>gdalinfo 02AUG12WV020800012AUG02114451-P1BS-052766399070_01_P001.ntf
Driver: NITF/National Imagery Transmission Format
Files: 02AUG12WV020800012AUG02114451-P1BS-052766399070_01_P001.ntf
Size is 33792, 35840
Coordinate System is `'
GCP Projection =
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
GCP[  0]: Id=UpperLeft, Info=
          (0.5,0.5) -> (-4.27916666666667,50.4708333333333,0)
GCP[  1]: Id=UpperRight, Info=
          (33791.5,0.5) -> (-4.04416666666667,50.4688888888889,0)
GCP[  2]: Id=LowerRight, Info=
          (33791.5,35839.5) -> (-4.045,50.3116666666667,0)
GCP[  3]: Id=LowerLeft, Info=
          (0.5,35839.5) -> (-4.27888888888889,50.3133333333333,0)
Metadata:
  NITF_ABPP=11
  NITF_CCS_COLUMN=0
  NITF_CCS_ROW=0
  NITF_CLEVEL=06
  NITF_CSDIDA_DAY=02
  NITF_CSDIDA_MONTH=AUG
  NITF_CSDIDA_OPERATION=000
  NITF_CSDIDA_PASS=08
  NITF_CSDIDA_PLATFORM_CODE=WV
  NITF_CSDIDA_PROCESS_TIME=20120802123318
  NITF_CSDIDA_PRODUCT_ID=P1
  NITF_CSDIDA_RESERVED_0=0000
  NITF_CSDIDA_RESERVED_1=00
  NITF_CSDIDA_RESERVED_2=01
  NITF_CSDIDA_RESERVED_3=N
  NITF_CSDIDA_RESERVED_4=N
  NITF_CSDIDA_SENSOR_ID=AA
  NITF_CSDIDA_SOFTWARE_VERSION_NUMBER=4.15
  NITF_CSDIDA_TIME=20120802114451
  NITF_CSDIDA_VEHICLE_ID=02
  NITF_CSDIDA_YEAR=2012
  NITF_CSEXRA_ALONG_SCAN_GSD=019.8
  NITF_CSEXRA_ANGLE_TO_NORTH=270.000
  NITF_CSEXRA_AZ_OF_OBLIQUITY=144.353
  NITF_CSEXRA_A_S_VERT_GSD=N/A
  NITF_CSEXRA_CIRCL_ERR=016
  NITF_CSEXRA_CROSS_SCAN_GSD=019.7
  NITF_CSEXRA_C_S_VERT_GSD=N/A
  NITF_CSEXRA_DYNAMIC_RANGE=01943
  NITF_CSEXRA_GEO_MEAN_GSD=019.8
  NITF_CSEXRA_GEO_MEAN_VERT_GSD=N/A
  NITF_CSEXRA_GRD_COVER=9
  NITF_CSEXRA_GSD_BETA_ANGLE=089.3
  NITF_CSEXRA_LINEAR_ERR=016
  NITF_CSEXRA_MAX_GSD=019.8
  NITF_CSEXRA_NUM_LINES=0035840
  NITF_CSEXRA_NUM_SAMPLES=33792
  NITF_CSEXRA_OBLIQUITY_ANGLE=07.329
  NITF_CSEXRA_PREDICTED_NIIRS=5.0
  NITF_CSEXRA_SENSOR=PAN
  NITF_CSEXRA_SNOW_DEPTH_CAT=9
  NITF_CSEXRA_SUN_AZIMUTH=163.442
  NITF_CSEXRA_SUN_ELEVATION=+56.504
  NITF_CSEXRA_TIME_FIRST_LINE_IMAGE=42291.718576
  NITF_CSEXRA_TIME_IMAGE_DURATION=00001.852000
  NITF_ENCRYP=0
  NITF_FBKGC=126,126,126
  NITF_FDT=20120802123318
  NITF_FHDR=NITF02.10
  NITF_FSCATP=
  NITF_FSCAUT=
  NITF_FSCLAS=U
  NITF_FSCLSY=US
  NITF_FSCLTX=
  NITF_FSCODE=
  NITF_FSCOP=00000
  NITF_FSCPYS=00000
  NITF_FSCRSN=
  NITF_FSCTLH=0
  NITF_FSCTLN=
  NITF_FSDCDT=
  NITF_FSDCTP=
  NITF_FSDCXM=
  NITF_FSDG=
  NITF_FSDGDT=
  NITF_FSREL=
  NITF_FSSRDT=
  NITF_FTITLE=12AUG02114451-P1BS-052766399070_01_P001.NTF
  NITF_IALVL=0
  NITF_IC=C8
  NITF_ICAT=VIS
  NITF_ICORDS=G
  NITF_IDATIM=20120802114451
  NITF_IDLVL=1
  NITF_IGEOLO=502815N0041645W502808N0040239W501842N0040242W501848N0041644W
  NITF_IID1=P11A760A00
  NITF_IID2=02AUG12WV020800012AUG02114451-P1BS-052766399070_01_P001
  NITF_ILOC_COLUMN=0
  NITF_ILOC_ROW=0
  NITF_IMAG=1.0
  NITF_IMAGE_COMMENTS=The imagery and metadata data on this media is the property of                  DigitalGlobe and is licensed for use only. All use must be in                   accordance with the terms of the license that accompanies the media.            If the license is purchased under contract NMA 301 99 D003, use is              in accordance with the license therein
  NITF_IMODE=B
  NITF_IREP=MONO
  NITF_ISCATP=
  NITF_ISCAUT=
  NITF_ISCLAS=U
  NITF_ISCLSY=US
  NITF_ISCLTX=
  NITF_ISCODE=
  NITF_ISCRSN=
  NITF_ISCTLH=0
  NITF_ISCTLN=
  NITF_ISDCDT=
  NITF_ISDCTP=
  NITF_ISDCXM=
  NITF_ISDG=
  NITF_ISDGDT=
  NITF_ISORCE=DigitalGlobe
  NITF_ISREL=
  NITF_ISSRDT=
  NITF_ONAME=DigitalGlobe
  NITF_OPHONE=+1(800)496-1225
  NITF_OSTAID=DG
  NITF_PIAIMC_CAMSPECS=
  NITF_PIAIMC_CLOUDCVR=999
  NITF_PIAIMC_COMGEN=00
  NITF_PIAIMC_ESD=Y
  NITF_PIAIMC_GENERATION=1
  NITF_PIAIMC_IDATUM=WGE
  NITF_PIAIMC_IELLIP=
  NITF_PIAIMC_IPROJ=
  NITF_PIAIMC_MEANGSD=00019.8
  NITF_PIAIMC_OTHERCOND=
  NITF_PIAIMC_PIAMSNNUM=
  NITF_PIAIMC_PREPROC=1R
  NITF_PIAIMC_PROJID=
  NITF_PIAIMC_SATTRACK=00000000
  NITF_PIAIMC_SENSMODE=PUSHBROOM
  NITF_PIAIMC_SENSNAME=WV02
  NITF_PIAIMC_SOURCE=DigitalGlobe Acquired Image
  NITF_PIAIMC_SRP=Y
  NITF_PIAIMC_SUBQUAL=
  NITF_PJUST=R
  NITF_PVTYPE=INT
  NITF_STDIDC_ACQUISITION_DATE=20120802114451
  NITF_STDIDC_COUNTRY=UK
  NITF_STDIDC_END_COLUMN=033
  NITF_STDIDC_END_ROW=00035
  NITF_STDIDC_END_SEGMENT=AA
  NITF_STDIDC_LOCATION=5028N00410W
  NITF_STDIDC_MISSION=WV02
  NITF_STDIDC_OP_NUM=000
  NITF_STDIDC_PASS=08
  NITF_STDIDC_REPLAY_REGEN=000
  NITF_STDIDC_REPRO_NUM=00
  NITF_STDIDC_START_COLUMN=001
  NITF_STDIDC_START_ROW=00001
  NITF_STDIDC_START_SEGMENT=AA
  NITF_STDIDC_WAC=
  NITF_STYPE=BF01
  NITF_TGTID=
  NITF_USE00A_ANGLE_TO_NORTH=270
  NITF_USE00A_DYNAMIC_RANGE=02046
  NITF_USE00A_MAX_LP_SEG=034984
  NITF_USE00A_MEAN_GSD=019.8
  NITF_USE00A_N_REF=00
  NITF_USE00A_N_SEG=001
  NITF_USE00A_OBL_ANG=07.33
  NITF_USE00A_REV_NUM=14777
  NITF_USE00A_ROLL_ANG=-04.40
  NITF_USE00A_SUN_AZ=163.4
  NITF_USE00A_SUN_EL=+56.5
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=JPEG2000
RPC Metadata:
  HEIGHT_OFF=185
  HEIGHT_SCALE=500
  LAT_OFF=50.3912
  LAT_SCALE=0.0801
  LINE_DEN_COEFF=1 -7.097299e-05 0.0002958112 -0.0001099816 -3.246122e-06 -4.477109e-08 -1.080242e-07 1.936947e-06 -1.719027e-06 4.993111e-07 -1.138078e-07 -1.174706e-08 -8.276990999999999e-06 0 -1.421757e-08 -0.0001801106 -2.373316e-08 0 -3.581652e-06 0
  LINE_NUM_COEFF=-0.000399985 -0.01005722 -1.01753 -0.006779946 -5.884052e-05 -1.635923e-06 -0.0001055135 -0.0006862205 0.0006496178 -2.416407e-07 -7.647635e-08 -5.179394e-08 -4.590663e-06 0 1.435899e-06 -2.188919e-06 -5.184367e-07 -7.571524e-08 -1.420922e-07 0
  LINE_OFF=17491
  LINE_SCALE=17492
  LONG_OFF=-4.1618
  LONG_SCALE=0.118
  MAX_LAT=50.43125
  MAX_LONG=-4.1028
  MIN_LAT=50.35115
  MIN_LONG=-4.220800000000001
  SAMP_DEN_COEFF=1 0.0003695722 0.001258215 -0.0003607042 -1.898228e-06 -5.071584e-07 4.194822e-07 1.924302e-06 3.429375e-06 -2.679075e-06 -3.306901e-08 0 -2.084528e-07 0 -7.805705e-08 -1.627469e-07 0 0 1.189265e-08 0
  SAMP_NUM_COEFF=-0.001720036 1.007764 -0.0008194283 -0.005161962 -0.001250569 0.000348986 -0.000142544 0.001354211 0.0002281915 -2.394869e-06 -3.79588e-07 -4.926172e-06 -6.307797e-06 -2.503513e-06 2.083475e-05 0.0001637396 -4.854612e-08 8.713399e-07 3.410511e-06 1.235957e-08
  SAMP_OFF=16613
  SAMP_SCALE=16614
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (    0.0,    0.0)
Lower Left  (    0.0,35840.0)
Upper Right (33792.0,    0.0)
Lower Right (33792.0,35840.0)
Center      (16896.0,17920.0)
Band 1 Block=256x256 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Gray
  Overviews: 16896x17920, 8448x8960, 4224x4480, 2112x2240, 1056x1120, 528x560, 264x280, 132x140
  Image Structure Metadata:
    NBITS=11
```

**Multispectral gdalinfo**:

```
F:\GIS\CD5514>gdalinfo 02AUG12WV020800012AUG02114451-M1BS-052766399070_01_P001.ntf
Driver: NITF/National Imagery Transmission Format
Files: 02AUG12WV020800012AUG02114451-M1BS-052766399070_01_P001.ntf
       02AUG12WV020800012AUG02114451-M1BS-052766399070_01_P001.ntf.aux.xml
Size is 9216, 9216
Coordinate System is `'
GCP Projection =
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
GCP[  0]: Id=UpperLeft, Info=
          (0.5,0.5) -> (-4.27944444444444,50.4708333333333,0)
GCP[  1]: Id=UpperRight, Info=
          (9215.5,0.5) -> (-4.04388888888889,50.4688888888889,0)
GCP[  2]: Id=LowerRight, Info=
          (9215.5,9215.5) -> (-4.04472222222222,50.3116666666667,0)
GCP[  3]: Id=LowerLeft, Info=
          (0.5,9215.5) -> (-4.27916666666667,50.3133333333333,0)
Metadata:
  ESRI_MD_ACQUISITION_DATE=20120802114451
  ESRI_MD_ANGLE_TO_NORTH=270
  ESRI_MD_CE=016
  ESRI_MD_DATA_TYPE=Generic
  ESRI_MD_ISCLOUDCOVER=false
  ESRI_MD_LE=016
  ESRI_MD_PRODUCT_NAME=P2
  ESRI_MD_RASTER_FORMAT=NITF
  ESRI_MD_SENSOR_NAME=WV02
  ESRI_MD_SUN_AZIMUTH=163.437
  ESRI_MD_SUN_ELEVATION=+56.517
  NITF_ABPP=11
  NITF_CCS_COLUMN=0
  NITF_CCS_ROW=0
  NITF_CLEVEL=06
  NITF_CSDIDA_DAY=02
  NITF_CSDIDA_MONTH=AUG
  NITF_CSDIDA_OPERATION=000
  NITF_CSDIDA_PASS=08
  NITF_CSDIDA_PLATFORM_CODE=WV
  NITF_CSDIDA_PROCESS_TIME=20120802123318
  NITF_CSDIDA_PRODUCT_ID=P2
  NITF_CSDIDA_RESERVED_0=0000
  NITF_CSDIDA_RESERVED_1=00
  NITF_CSDIDA_RESERVED_2=01
  NITF_CSDIDA_RESERVED_3=N
  NITF_CSDIDA_RESERVED_4=N
  NITF_CSDIDA_SENSOR_ID=GA
  NITF_CSDIDA_SOFTWARE_VERSION_NUMBER=4.15
  NITF_CSDIDA_TIME=20120802114451
  NITF_CSDIDA_VEHICLE_ID=02
  NITF_CSDIDA_YEAR=2012
  NITF_CSEXRA_ALONG_SCAN_GSD=079.2
  NITF_CSEXRA_ANGLE_TO_NORTH=270.000
  NITF_CSEXRA_AZ_OF_OBLIQUITY=144.771
  NITF_CSEXRA_A_S_VERT_GSD=N/A
  NITF_CSEXRA_CIRCL_ERR=016
  NITF_CSEXRA_CROSS_SCAN_GSD=078.9
  NITF_CSEXRA_C_S_VERT_GSD=N/A
  NITF_CSEXRA_DYNAMIC_RANGE=02027
  NITF_CSEXRA_GEO_MEAN_GSD=079.1
  NITF_CSEXRA_GEO_MEAN_VERT_GSD=N/A
  NITF_CSEXRA_GRD_COVER=9
  NITF_CSEXRA_GSD_BETA_ANGLE=089.5
  NITF_CSEXRA_LINEAR_ERR=016
  NITF_CSEXRA_MAX_GSD=079.2
  NITF_CSEXRA_NUM_LINES=0009216
  NITF_CSEXRA_NUM_SAMPLES=09216
  NITF_CSEXRA_OBLIQUITY_ANGLE=07.329
  NITF_CSEXRA_PREDICTED_NIIRS=3.0
  NITF_CSEXRA_SENSOR=MS
  NITF_CSEXRA_SNOW_DEPTH_CAT=9
  NITF_CSEXRA_SUN_AZIMUTH=163.437
  NITF_CSEXRA_SUN_ELEVATION=+56.517
  NITF_CSEXRA_TIME_FIRST_LINE_IMAGE=42291.718656
  NITF_CSEXRA_TIME_IMAGE_DURATION=00001.852000
  NITF_ENCRYP=0
  NITF_FBKGC=126,126,126
  NITF_FDT=20120802123318
  NITF_FHDR=NITF02.10
  NITF_FSCATP=
  NITF_FSCAUT=
  NITF_FSCLAS=U
  NITF_FSCLSY=US
  NITF_FSCLTX=
  NITF_FSCODE=
  NITF_FSCOP=00000
  NITF_FSCPYS=00000
  NITF_FSCRSN=
  NITF_FSCTLH=0
  NITF_FSCTLN=
  NITF_FSDCDT=
  NITF_FSDCTP=
  NITF_FSDCXM=
  NITF_FSDG=
  NITF_FSDGDT=
  NITF_FSREL=
  NITF_FSSRDT=
  NITF_FTITLE=12AUG02114451-M1BS-052766399070_01_P001.NTF
  NITF_IALVL=0
  NITF_IC=C8
  NITF_ICAT=MS
  NITF_ICORDS=G
  NITF_IDATIM=20120802114451
  NITF_IDLVL=1
  NITF_IGEOLO=502815N0041646W502808N0040238W501842N0040241W501848N0041645W
  NITF_IID1=M11A760A00
  NITF_IID2=02AUG12WV020800012AUG02114451-M1BS-052766399070_01_P001
  NITF_ILOC_COLUMN=0
  NITF_ILOC_ROW=0
  NITF_IMAG=1.0
  NITF_IMAGE_COMMENTS=The imagery and metadata data on this media is the property of                  DigitalGlobe and is licensed for use only. All use must be in                   accordance with the terms of the license that accompanies the media.            If the license is purchased under contract NMA 301 99 D003, use is              in accordance with the license therein
  NITF_IMODE=B
  NITF_IREP=MULTI
  NITF_ISCATP=
  NITF_ISCAUT=
  NITF_ISCLAS=U
  NITF_ISCLSY=US
  NITF_ISCLTX=
  NITF_ISCODE=
  NITF_ISCRSN=
  NITF_ISCTLH=0
  NITF_ISCTLN=
  NITF_ISDCDT=
  NITF_ISDCTP=
  NITF_ISDCXM=
  NITF_ISDG=
  NITF_ISDGDT=
  NITF_ISORCE=DigitalGlobe
  NITF_ISREL=
  NITF_ISSRDT=
  NITF_ONAME=DigitalGlobe
  NITF_OPHONE=+1(800)496-1225
  NITF_OSTAID=DG
  NITF_PIAIMC_CAMSPECS=
  NITF_PIAIMC_CLOUDCVR=999
  NITF_PIAIMC_COMGEN=00
  NITF_PIAIMC_ESD=Y
  NITF_PIAIMC_GENERATION=1
  NITF_PIAIMC_IDATUM=WGE
  NITF_PIAIMC_IELLIP=
  NITF_PIAIMC_IPROJ=
  NITF_PIAIMC_MEANGSD=00079.1
  NITF_PIAIMC_OTHERCOND=
  NITF_PIAIMC_PIAMSNNUM=
  NITF_PIAIMC_PREPROC=1R
  NITF_PIAIMC_PROJID=
  NITF_PIAIMC_SATTRACK=00000000
  NITF_PIAIMC_SENSMODE=PUSHBROOM
  NITF_PIAIMC_SENSNAME=WV02
  NITF_PIAIMC_SOURCE=DigitalGlobe Acquired Image
  NITF_PIAIMC_SRP=Y
  NITF_PIAIMC_SUBQUAL=
  NITF_PJUST=R
  NITF_PVTYPE=INT
  NITF_STDIDC_ACQUISITION_DATE=20120802114451
  NITF_STDIDC_COUNTRY=UK
  NITF_STDIDC_END_COLUMN=009
  NITF_STDIDC_END_ROW=00009
  NITF_STDIDC_END_SEGMENT=AA
  NITF_STDIDC_LOCATION=5028N00410W
  NITF_STDIDC_MISSION=WV02
  NITF_STDIDC_OP_NUM=000
  NITF_STDIDC_PASS=08
  NITF_STDIDC_REPLAY_REGEN=000
  NITF_STDIDC_REPRO_NUM=00
  NITF_STDIDC_START_COLUMN=001
  NITF_STDIDC_START_ROW=00001
  NITF_STDIDC_START_SEGMENT=AA
  NITF_STDIDC_WAC=
  NITF_STYPE=BF01
  NITF_TGTID=
  NITF_USE00A_ANGLE_TO_NORTH=270
  NITF_USE00A_DYNAMIC_RANGE=02046
  NITF_USE00A_MAX_LP_SEG=008746
  NITF_USE00A_MEAN_GSD=079.1
  NITF_USE00A_N_REF=00
  NITF_USE00A_N_SEG=001
  NITF_USE00A_OBL_ANG=07.33
  NITF_USE00A_REV_NUM=14777
  NITF_USE00A_ROLL_ANG=-04.40
  NITF_USE00A_SUN_AZ=163.4
  NITF_USE00A_SUN_EL=+56.5
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=JPEG2000
RPC Metadata:
  HEIGHT_OFF=185
  HEIGHT_SCALE=500
  LAT_OFF=50.3912
  LAT_SCALE=0.0801
  LINE_DEN_COEFF=1 -7.102672e-05 0.0003386837 -0.0001098412 -3.259125e-06 -4.477885e-08 -1.082368e-07 1.959975e-06 -1.738605e-06 4.95656e-07 -1.142162e-07 -1.187174e-08 -8.306679000000001e-06 0 -1.416616e-08 -0.0001801384 -2.374098e-08 0 -3.582201e-06 0
  LINE_NUM_COEFF=-0.0003142294 -0.01009132 -1.01753 -0.006779956 -5.966242e-05 -1.644152e-06 -0.0001059468 -0.0006908824 0.0006060163 -2.425475e-07 -7.707831e-08 -5.254936e-08 -4.610493e-06 0 1.40595e-06 -2.135712e-06 -5.147893e-07 -7.63954e-08 -1.509679e-07 0
  LINE_OFF=4372
  LINE_SCALE=4373
  LONG_OFF=-4.1618
  LONG_SCALE=0.1184
  MAX_LAT=50.4708333333333385
  MAX_LONG=-4.04388888888888864
  MIN_LAT=50.3116666666666603
  MIN_LONG=-4.27944444444444461
  SAMP_DEN_COEFF=1 0.0004608863 0.001258952 -0.0003611522 -1.961344e-06 -5.099593e-07 4.147246e-07 2.117414e-06 3.435577e-06 -2.690275e-06 -3.288508e-08 0 -2.088179e-07 0 -8.007819e-08 -1.773008e-07 0 0 1.154247e-08 0
  SAMP_NUM_COEFF=-0.001906619 1.008388 -0.0008174169 -0.005147639 -0.001250673 0.0003482868 -0.0001421538 0.001450459 0.0002275686 -2.385416e-06 -3.949045e-07 -4.692355e-06 -6.285973e-06 -2.517055e-06 2.063487e-05 0.0001633097 -4.831784e-08 9.367542e-07 3.401303e-06 1.23849e-08
  SAMP_OFF=4164
  SAMP_SCALE=4165
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (    0.0,    0.0)
Lower Left  (    0.0, 9216.0)
Upper Right ( 9216.0,    0.0)
Lower Right ( 9216.0, 9216.0)
Center      ( 4608.0, 4608.0)
Band 1 Block=256x256 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Blue
  Overviews: 4608x4608, 2304x2304, 1152x1152, 576x576, 288x288, 144x144
  Image Structure Metadata:
    NBITS=11
Band 2 Block=256x256 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Green
  Overviews: 4608x4608, 2304x2304, 1152x1152, 576x576, 288x288, 144x144
  Image Structure Metadata:
    NBITS=11
Band 3 Block=256x256 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Red
  Overviews: 4608x4608, 2304x2304, 1152x1152, 576x576, 288x288, 144x144
  Image Structure Metadata:
    NBITS=11
Band 4 Block=256x256 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Undefined
  Overviews: 4608x4608, 2304x2304, 1152x1152, 576x576, 288x288, 144x144
  Image Structure Metadata:
    NBITS=11
```

Comment: Does this "jumping-around" phenomenon occur when you load the multi-spectral data only? (I mean, I want to understand if pan layer was affecting). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Seems it was a change to default settings in QGIS 3.10 for CRS (see below) which meant newly loaded assets had no projection - classed as 'invalid projected' unless you specifically set it.

So I changed it back to how it was, because this was messing up new layers and particularly seemed to upset the multispectral raster in this instance.

[image]

Switching to 'Use project CRS' resolved my issue.